# Clustered Index Scan instead of Clustered Index Seek on left join

Tags: sql-server, indexing

```
SELECT *
FROM
    tbl_transaction t
LEFT JOIN
    tbl_transaction_hsbc ht
ON 
    t.transactionid = ht.transactionid
```

`transactionid` on both tables is the primary key so why no index seek?

Comment: primary key does not necessarily imply cluster index..

Comment: @Pabloker clustered or not doesn't really matter. How would a seek work in either case?

Comment: If you had to read aloud every person's last name, first name, and phone number in the New York Metropolitan area phone book, would you want to do it by pages in order (scan) or would you prefer to go ordered by phone number using a reverse phone index that only had phone and last name in it, looking up each last name out of alphabetical order and finding the first name associated with the current phone number (bookmark lookup/seek)?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand. You are right. I put my comment based in this phrase:`transactionid` **on both tables is the primary key**.

Comment: @Pabloker I don't know how it's relevant whether it's clustered or not. Anyway the title of the question also said it's clustered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe it's the SELECT * ... and maybe because you're returning the entire table, there is no advantage to seeking. What do you want a seek to do, seek incrementally to every row? A scan is much more efficient.

I realize you've probably read or been told to avoid scans at all cost. I think there needs to be more context associated with that. Sometimes a scan is the right answer and the most efficient path to the data. If there query is slow, perhaps you could show an actual execution plan, and we can help pinpoint the problem. But the answer isn't going to be forcing this query to use a seek.

Comment: Exactly, a full scan beats a (range) seek quite often because a scan doesn't need a lookup +1

Comment: Here's what I've got in mind.... for each row in tbl_transaction it scans the index on tbl_transaction_hsbc for the row to join to. I was thinking that if it was a seek instead then it wouldn't need to scan the entire index everytime it looked up the row to join to - it would be able to look it up much more quickly. I guess I don't understand these mechanisms...

Comment: If it does a scan, it doesn't need to do any lookup at all - the data is already right there on the pages it's scanning. It doesn't scan the entire index for every row, it scans the entire index ONCE.

Answer (score 1):

No index seek because you don't have a where clause.
Index seek means you check a range of values in the index.
As you have no where clause, there is no other choice but to scan all the index values.
So the name "index scan".

It's not a table scan, it's an index scan. If you don't have an index on this column in one of the tables, you'll have table scan for second table + index scan for first table.